# How to build a jar library

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to build a library with netbeans, I'm building so:
New project...Java...Java application:

```
package somma;

public class Somma {

   public static int somma(int a, int b) {
      int s = a + b;
      return s;

   }
}
```

With this main

```
package somma;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int a = 1;
      int b = 2;
      int s = Somma.somma(a, b);
      System.out.println(s);

   }

}
```

After that, right click on the project...properties...Buid...Packaging....click on the project again and clean and build. Now I created a Somma.jar, for to try the new library I build an exmple project:

```
package uselibrary;

import static somma.Somma.somma;

public class UseLibrary {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int a = 1;
      int b = 2;
      int s = somma(a, b);
      System.out.println(s);
   }
}
```

Run correctly, but there is a problem, when I import the library, I would like to avoid this name **import static somma.Somma.somma;** I would like to change with this name **import somma;** 
How can I do that ?

Comment: First of all: Dont do static imports in that case. To your problem: ignore it! Imports are made like this, its the path to the package / class. You could say import somma.* but thats not recommend if you dont really lose kind a everything of that package.

Comment: Hi Luftbaum, I tried without static, but don't functions, the problem could be how I built the method. I have to write only :** import somma;**

Answer (score 0):

Okay try this edit

```
package somma;

public class Somma {

   public int somma(int a, int b) {
      int s = a + b;
      return s;

   }
}
```

And

```
package uselibrary;

import somma.Somma;

public class useLibrary {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Somma som = new Somma();
      int a = 1;
      int b = 2;
      int s = som.somma(a, b);
      System.out.println(s);
   }
}
```

Comment: @Frank Pentangeli, this worked pretty well right, because I tested it myself.